# Tradeoffs of larger or smaller k in k-fold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

While I was reading about K-fold. I got a Question.

On average, With a higher number of folds, the estimated cross- validation error will be higher or smaller?

I think the CV error will go up, but I'm not sure. is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Using higher number of folds, you will reduce the bais but increase variance. Also your runtime will increase. Bias and variance trade off is always there. If you have very small dataset then smaller K value is recommended because there wont be enough datapoints in each fold for the machine to learn effectively.

Comment: My question is asking about the CV error. So Can you answer about it please?